# CellAlignment right based on specific data "FAST EXCEL LARAVEL"

Tags: laravel, spout, fast-excel

im trying to cellAlignment right for number_format data only Total Share,Total Contribution and Monthly Contribution not all data at once, how i to make it? this is my code :

```
public function generateExcel(){
    
    return response()->streamDownload(function () {
        $header_style = (new StyleBuilder())
            ->setFontBold()
            ->setShouldWrapText(false)
            ->build();
        $rows_style = (new StyleBuilder())
            ->setShouldWrapText(false)
            ->build();
        $right_style = (new StyleBuilder())
            ->setCellAlignment(CellAlignment::RIGHT)
            ->build();
    return (new FastExcel($this->renderReportList()))
        ->headerStyle($header_style)
        ->rowsStyle($rows_style)
        ->export('php://output' , function ($item) {
        $data = [
            'Membership No'             => $item->ref_no,
            'Name'                      => $item->name,
            'Total Share'               => number_format($item->total_share,2),
            'Total Contribution'        => number_format($item->total_contribution,2),
            'Monthly Contribution'      => number_format($item->monthly_contribution,2),
        ];
        return $data;
});
}, sprintf('example-%s.xlsx',$this->startDate));
```